# Как изменить стили блока добавленного через js и innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css, массивы, функции

Добавляю карточки со странами циклом и innerHtml, предварительно получив данные к этим карточкам по API.

```
function displayCountries(array) {
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        countries.innerHTML += `<div class="card">
    <div class="flag">
    <img class="flag-img" src="${array[i].flags.png}" alt="flag">
    </div>
    <div class="description">
    <h6 class="country">${array[i].name.common}</h6>
    <p Population: class="population">Population: <span class="population-text">${array[i].population}</span>
    </p>
    <p Region: class="region">Region: <span class="region-text">${array[i].region}</span></p>
    <p Capital: class="capital">Capital: <span class="capital-text">${array[i].capital === undefined ? '--/--' : array[i].capital}</span></p>
    </div>
    </div>`
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<section class="main-section">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="countries">
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

И позже я не могу удалить допустим класс card и добавить другой класс. При том другие классы, которые были уже заданы изначально в HTML, а не добавлены через js работают исправно.
При выводе в консоль классов card получаю просто пустой массив.

```
const card = document.querySelectorAll('.card')
console.log(card)
```

Помогите, незнаю как это нагуглить даже

Comment: Нет никакой разницы как сформирован ДОМ... Статично или скриптом... Скорее всего ты что-то делаешь не так или не в тот момент времени. Если бы был полный пример - тогда твоя проблема была бы более понятна.